# Simple calculation in imprecise probability urn example

Tags: probability, bayesian, imprecise-probability

In Miranda and de Cooman's chapter 3, ["Structural judgements"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9781118763117.ch3/summary), in Augustin et al.'s *Introduction to Imprecise Probability*, example 3.4 on p. 65 shows that independence in the selection (type-2 independence) does not imply strong independence (type-3 independence) for lower previsions.  One of the numerical values in the example seems incorrect to me.  I'm not sure whether there is a typo (there is an obvious trivial typo at the top of the same page, so this seems possible), or whether I don't fully understand the example (quite plausible).

There are two possible configurations, or compositions, for a pair of urns containing red ($R$) and green ($G$) balls, but we don't know which configuration is actual.  Given a configuration, draws from each urn are random, i.e. independent.

> Configuration 1:    Urn 1: $\{R, R, G\}$     Urn 2: $\{R,R,G\}$

> Configuration 2:    Urn 1: $\{R, G, G\}$     Urn 2: $\{R,G,G\}$

Let $X_k$ be the r.v. representing the outcome of the draw from the $k$th urn.  The text claims that given this setup, the lower prevision $\underline P$ of $X_1=R$ & $X_2=G$ is
\begin{equation}
\underline P(X_1 = R, X_2=G) = \frac{4}{9} .
\end{equation}
It seems to me that this value should be 2/9.  Since the draws are independent within each configuration, the probability (linear prevision) corresponding to configuration 1 is
\begin{equation}
P(X_1 = R, X_2=G) = P(X_1=R) \times P(X_2=G) = \frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{9} .
\end{equation}
Similarly, the probability corresponding to configuration 2 is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{9} .
\end{equation}
Since the lower prevision is the lower envelope of the probabilities in this example, it seems to follow that $\underline P(X_1 = R, X_2=G) = 2/9$.  However, I suspect that I've interpreted the example incorrectly in some respect or have some more basic misunderstanding.

(I believe that if 2/9 were the correct value here, the example would still illustrate the point that independence in the selection doesn't imply strong independence.  For that point all that's needed is that $\underline P(X_1 = R, X_2=G) > 1/9$.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am one of the authors of the book. Indeed it is a typo, sorry it caused some misunderstanding... feel free to contact me if you have further questions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Your contact details belong in your profile.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed, $\tfrac 29$ appears to be the correct value for that setup.

It looks to be a poty.

Comment: Agreed. I double checked the treatment in the book, and indeed 2/9 should be the correct value here.