# Notation in this imprecise Markov chain upper transition operator definition

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, markov-process, imprecise-probability

In Example 11.6 on p. 270 of Hermans and Škulj's "Stochastic Processes" in [Augustin et al.'s *Introduction to Imprecise Probabilities*](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Introduction+to+Imprecise+Probabilities-p-9780470973813), there is a definition of an upper transition operator as $$\overline T=I_{\cal X} \max$$

$\overline T$ is an upper prevision (upper expectation) operator, where for any function $f$ on the set of atomic outcomes $\cal X$, $\overline Tf := \overline Q (f|x)$, the upper conditional prevision of $f$ conditional on any value $x\in \cal X$ (11.8, p. 266).

I'm having trouble interpreting $I_{\cal X} \max$ in this context.  I assume that $\max$ applied to $f$ is just supposed to find the maximum value of $f$ over all $x\in \cal X$.  That seems reasonable.

I'm confused by seeing $I_{\cal X}$ next to $\max$, though.  I take $I_{\cal X}$ to be the indicator function for $\cal X$, the entire space (see e.g. p. 260).  This function returns 1 for any value at all, i.e. in this context, for any value in $\cal X$.  So assuming that the range of $f$ is in $\cal X$, $I_{\cal X} (\max f)$ aways returns 1.

EDIT (revision that more accurately reflects other material in the same example):

That could be a sensible value for $\overline T$ in the example in which the definition appears, but if that interpretation is correct, then why give such a complicated definition for the function that simply returns 1 when passed any function on $\cal X$?

Further, in the subsequent equations that depend on this definition, $\max$ appears repeatedly.  I don't believe that all of the instances of $\max$ come from this definition, but in no cases is the value of $\max$ ignored in such a way that 1 is always returned.  This suggests that I am completely misinterpreting $\overline T=I_{\cal X} \max$.

Comment: I do not think ‘fuzzy-logic’ is appropriate for this question.

Comment: Thanks @equaeghe.  I've removed the fuzzy-logic tag.  It's hard to know what tags to use until there is an imprecise-probability tag available (or something with a similar meaning).

Comment: I would not add the fuzzy-logic tag as a replacement for imprecise-probability, as these are different things. It is true that both are sometimes used with similar goals.

Comment: @equaeghe  I've removed fuzzy-logic from [another IP question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2301738/simple-calculation-in-imprecise-probability-urn-example) a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator $\overline{T}$ maps functions on $\mathcal{X}$ to functions on $\mathcal{X}$. So $\overline{T}=I_{\mathcal{X}}\max$ means that $\overline{T}(f)(x)=I_{\mathcal{X}}(x)\max(f)=\max(f)$ for any function $f$ on $\mathcal{X}$ and $x$ in $\mathcal{X}$.

To understand the reasoning behind this notation, it is useful to first look at functions of scalars: Let $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x^2$. Now, we can multiply this function by a constant $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}$ to get another function, i.e., let $q=\alpha p$, meaning $q:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto \alpha x^2$. You can do this because $\alpha$ belongs to the range of $p$.

Similarly, with transition operators—functions of a specific class of functions to (the same) specific class of functions—you can do the same. And also here the natural ‘constants’ belong to the range *of the operator*. So constants are functions in this case. (This holds because multiplication is well-defined for this space of functions; namely pointwise multiplication.) So if $\overline{T}$ is a transition operator, then $g\overline{T}$, with $g$ some function on $\mathcal{X}$, is as well (perhaps not coherent, but that is not important in this argument).

In this particular case, we are not exactly in this situation, because $\max$ is not a transition operator and the multiplication with $I_{\mathcal{X}}$ is necessary to build one from it. Nevertheless, the idea that the notion of a constant is relative, is key here to understand the notation, I think.

Comment: Thanks very much equaghe.  This is very much appreciated.  It didn't occur to me the $x$ would directly become the argument of $I_{\cal X}$.  So even though $I_{\cal X}(x)$ is always 1, so in one sense it doesn't do any work, in another sense it needs to be there so that the resulting so that result of $\overline T(f)$ remains a function of $x$, and doesn't just turn into the scalar $\max(f)$.  Is that the idea?  Sorry to keep asking additional questions.

Comment: Also, it looks like the general rule of thumb is to read expressions like $I_{\cal X} \max$ in such a way that whatever parameters of the component functions can't be filled by one kind of argument are left for an argument of another kind.  What I mean is, in this case the first argument to $I_{\cal X} \max$ is $f$, so that gets sent to $\max$, because $\max$ can accept an argument of the type $f$, but it makes no sense to apply $\max$ to a single element of $\cal X$. But $I_{\cal X}$ does apply to elements of $\cal X$, not to functions on $\cal X$, so $x$ gets sent to $I_{\cal X}$. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, see my edit.

Comment: Ah--that clarifies a point about notation that had contributed to my confusion: i.e. that $I_{\cal X}$ is written before $\max$, even though $\max f$ is a scalar while $I_{\cal X}$ is a function.  This makes sense now.  Thanks.  Wonderful.